# Nokia map embed - hide labels and roads

Tags: label, maps, embed

Regarding embedding a Nokia map in a web page:

Anyone know how I can hide roads and names. Like on here.com they have a checkbox under feature to hide 'labels'.

This is what I have so far:

```
       var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById("map"),
       {
         'components': [ 
        // Behavior collection
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar() 

        ],
            'zoomLevel': 18,       
    'baseMapType': nokia.maps.map.Display.SATELLITE          
   });
```

Comment: Found the answer should anyone else struggle as I did:

    'baseMapType': nokia.maps.map.Display.SATELLITE_PLAIN